# ForeignKey forms and unbound form issues

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `User` and `Freelancer`:

```
#models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

class Freelancer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have two forms:

```
#forms.py
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

class FreelanceUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        fields = ('first_name', 'surname', 'university', 'biography', 'skills')
```

I want to display both on the same page, so I've created a view to do that:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        freelancer_form = FreelanceUpdateForm(request. POST, instance=request.user.id)

        if all([user_form.is_valid(), freelancer_form.is_valid()]):
            user = user_form.save()
            freelancer_form = freelancer_form.save()
            return redirect(user)
    else:
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        freelancer_form = FreelanceUpdateForm(instance=request.user.id)

    return render(request, 'freelancestudent/profile.html',{
        'user_form': user_form,
        'freelancer_form': freelancer_form,
    })
```

The problem is I can't get a `freelancer_form` with `freelancer_form = FreelanceUpdateForm(instance=request.user.id)` I've tried `freelancer_form = FreelanceUpdateForm(instance=Freelancer(user_id=request.user.id))` which populates the table but it won't save it as valid because it's not bound.

How do I get the relevant Freelancer??

Comment: I don't understand why you want to pass `user.id` to the freelance form. An instance is not an id.

Comment: `pk` is a relic from a previous iteration. I haven't removed it yet.

Comment: You haven't explained the error. Where is the form unbound? Show the traceback.

Answer (score -1):

For that you need to specity `related_name` in `Freelancer.user` to have reverse access to it:

```
class Freelancer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='freelancer')
```

Now you can access `Freelancer` from `User` model with simple `User.freelancer`, so you can create your form like this:

```
freelancer_form = FreelanceUpdateForm(request. POST, instance=request.user.freelancer)
```